# Jquery Mobile horizontal buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Argh, one of these that is doing my head in.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmHTc/41/

Three buttons supposed to be inline, code looks good but I can't get them not to be on a line each...  anyone figure it out?

JQuery Mobile 1.1.0.

Thanks as always!

Comment: Your actually using jQuery Mobile 1.0 in your fiddle. Why not use the latest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the listview.

```
<div data-role='controlgroup' data-type="horizontal">
    <a href='?page=tickets&igstatus=0' data-role='button' data-transition='fade'>New</a>
    <a href='?page=tickets&igstatus=1' data-role='button' data-transition='fade' class='ui-btn-active'>Pending</a>
    <a href='?page=tickets&igstatus=2' data-role='button' data-transition='fade'>Closed</a>
</div>
```